# Keras model.predict - expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have used the linked code to train my model. [RNN Prediction](https://github.com/Zaneaussie/Cryptocurrency-predicting-RNN)

Now I want to use my trained model to make a prediction by loading the model, which I do with predict.py

However I seem to get dim errors and I have tried everything and just about tearing my hair out. Is anyone able to help me solve this?

PS: You can download the model, test.csv & predict.py to reproduce & please include the code for correctly loading the pandas dataframe in predict.py to have answer marked as complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to properly reshape the data before sending it to model.predict() .

```
import numpy as np
#dummy data
df1 = np.array([[[1,23,7,9,61,5,5,6]]])
print(df1.shape)  # gives (1, 1, 8)
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('RNN_Final-01-0.534.model')
prediction = model.predict(df1)
print("---->",prediction)
```

Comment: Thanks Ram. I tried running your code but get the following message WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 60, 8) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 60, 8), dtype=tf.float32, name='lstm_input'), name='lstm_input', description="created by layer 'lstm_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 1, 8).
[[0.4936518 0.5063482]] at least I get some sort of output from the model which is good to see and i feel one step closer. so the close price and volume are part of the 2 parameters what is the third?

Comment: in training script use `model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(None,8), return_sequences=True)) `  and train the model then during prediction it wont display that warning. In keras/tensorflow 1st dimension is batch size.

Comment: @Jo3Dirt Please up-vote or accept answer if its helpful.